# Spring JDBC template throws an Incorrect result size exception

Tags: sql, database, spring, postgresql, jdbc

I am getting an `exception` when I run the `jdbctemplate` to get the id from my table. The exception is:

```
org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0
```

I have the script as below:

```
CREATE TABLE LOGIN(
PERSON_ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
USERNAME VARCHAR(20) CHECK (USERNAME IS NOT NULL),
PASSWORD VARCHAR(20) CHECK (PASSWORD IS NOT NULL)
);
```

and the `jdbctemplate code` is:

```
@Override
public int getPersonId(UsernamePassword usernamePassword) {
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT PERSON_ID FROM LOGIN WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ?", Integer.class,
            usernamePassword.getUser_name(), usernamePassword.getPassword());

}
```

I also tried other methods that `jdbctemplate` provides, but I had no luck. I will appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JdbcTemplate's  `queryForObject`  expects that executed query will return  only one row. If you get 0 rows or more than 1 row that will result in `IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException`.

I guess in your case, `queryForObject`  is returning o rows or more than 1 row,

So if you don't want to catch this `IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException`, go for `query` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

According to [implementation of JdbcTemplate in Springframwork](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java), the number of returning rows should be exactly 1.

```
@Override
@Nullable
public <T> T queryForObject(String sql, Class<T> requiredType) throws DataAccessException {
    return queryForObject(sql, getSingleColumnRowMapper(requiredType));
}
```

If the number is 0, it will throw an `EmptyResultDataAccessException`.
If the number is larger than 1, it will throw an `IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException`.

```
@Nullable
public static <T> T nullableSingleResult(@Nullable Collection<T> results) throws IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException {
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(results)) {
        throw new EmptyResultDataAccessException(1);
    }
    if (results.size() > 1) {
        throw new IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException(1, results.size());
    }
    return results.iterator().next();
}
```